# Show Office 365 Authentication Dialog from bot in Microsoft Teams with context.Activity.CreateOAuthReplyAsync

Tags: authentication, oauth, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am creating a bot with Microsoft Bot Framework. The bot is using enterprise resources in Office 365, therefore I need authentication. If the user of the bot is not authenticated and an access token is not present, the bot prompts the user to logon, using context.Activity.CreateOAuthReplyAsync.
In the bot emulator, all of this works fine. The Office 365 authentication dialog is shown and the access token is available.

Not in Microsoft Teams. In Microsoft Teams, the Card shows, but when I hit the "Sign in" Button, nothing happens. I have done a quick edit, to distinguish the channels by channelId. I found an article on stackoverflow, to set the parameter asSignInCard to true, but nothing happens either.
What do I have to do, to get the authentication dialog for Office365 in Microsoft Teams?

My code is this:

```
        Activity reply = null;

        if (context.Activity.ChannelId.ToLower().CompareTo("msteams") == 0)
        {
            reply = await context.Activity
                .CreateOAuthReplyAsync(connectionName, "Hit \"Sign in\" and enter your Office 365 credentials.", "Sign in", true)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        else
        {
            reply = await context.Activity
                .CreateOAuthReplyAsync(connectionName, "Hit \"Sign in\" and enter your Office 365 credentials.", "Sign in")
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

        }
        await context.PostAsync(reply);

        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a manifest for your bot, and include token.botframework.com in your `validDomains[]` array? Make sure you've followed all the instructions documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-oauth-card) and see if that helps.

Comment: Additionally, there were a few hiccups with OAuth that a member of the support team created work arounds for: https://github.com/JasonSowers/AADv2Sample-Workarounds

Comment: I have added a manifest with token.botframework.com as validdomain, but that didn't do the magic.